# Regular expression to match anything except binary numbers in C#?

Tags: c#, regex, binary

I want to check whether the string includes only `0s` and `1s`, and nothing else. If it includes anything else apart from `0` and `1`, I want to catch it. Even if single character is something different than `0` or `1`.

I wrote the following regular expression, but it doesn't seem to catch anything.

```
private static int bin(string binaryNumber) {

    Regex rgx = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z2-9\p{P}\p{S}\s,]*$");
    if (rgx.IsMatch(binaryNumber)) {
        Console.WriteLine("Binary number should include only 0 and 1");
    }

    // rest removed for brevity
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: [6.3. Binary Numbers](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9781449327453/ch06s03.html).  See also https://regex101.com/r/xo4xmQ/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"[^01]+$");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"^[01]+$");
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than that try to inverse it.

Check if binaryNumber does NOT match Regex for binary numbers only.

```
private static int bin(string binaryNumber) {

  Regex rgx = new Regex(@"^[01]+$");
  if (!rgx.IsMatch(binaryNumber)) {
    Console.WriteLine("Binary number should include only 0 and 1");
  }

  // rest removed for brevity
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
^[01]*$
```

Accepts any number of digits, including none.

or

```
^[01]+$
```

Accepts one or more digits.